# Dynamically Updating Choice List in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app which allows the user to specify how many predictors they would and select each predictor accordingly. Can anybody tell me how I can make the choices for each subsequent predictor reflective of the previous
predictor selections?

For example, if Predictor 1 = cyl, then the choices for Predictor 2 would be {disp, drat, hp, mpg}. Then, if Predictor 2 = hp, then the choices for Predictor 3 would be {disp, drat, mpg}.

```
## libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

## store variable names
var_names <- mtcars %>% select(1:5) %>% colnames

ui <- fluidPage(
  ## select number of variables to use
  numericInput(inputId = "n_preds", 
               label = "Number Predictors", 
               value = 1, 
               min = 1,
               max = length(var_names)),
  ## store UI object for future use
  uiOutput("vars")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## create objects to store individual predictors
  predictors <- reactive(paste0("Predictor ", seq_len(input$n_preds)))
  ## generate dynamic UI
  output$vars <- renderUI({
    map(predictors(), ~ selectInput(inputId = .x, 
                                    label = .x, 
                                    choices = var_names,
                                    selected = isolate(input[[.x]])) %||% "")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a similar answer as @cwthom's, but I don't always delete every input and add it again, but dynamically insert/remove new inputs. This has the advantage that the previously chosen value for the predictors are preserved. Also, I need fewer `observer`s which maybe could be a bit faster.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

## store variable names
var_names <- mtcars %>% select(1:5) %>% colnames

ui <- fluidPage(
    ## select number of variables to use
  numericInput(inputId = "n_preds", 
               label = "Number Predictors", 
               value = 1, 
               min = 1,
               max = length(var_names)),
  # anchor where the inputs get added
  div(id = "add_vars")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  current_n_preds <- 0
  
  observeEvent(input$n_preds, {
    
    # add inputs
    if (input$n_preds > current_n_preds) {
      for (i in (current_n_preds + 1):input$n_preds) {
        possible_choices <- setdiff(var_names, preds_selected())
        insertUI(
          selector = "#add_vars",
          ui = div(
            id = paste0("Predictor_", i),
            selectInput(inputId = paste0("Predictor_", i),
                        label = paste0("Predictor ", i),
                        choices = possible_choices,
                        selected = possible_choices[1])
          )
        )
        
        current_n_preds <<- current_n_preds + 1
      }
    } else {
      # remove inputs
      for (i in current_n_preds:(input$n_preds + 1)) {
        removeUI(
          selector = paste0("#Predictor_", i)
        )
        current_n_preds <<- current_n_preds - 1
      }
    }
    
  })
  
  # vector of selected predictors
  preds_selected <- reactive({
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(input$n_preds), function(i) {
      input[[paste0("Predictor_", i)]]
    }))
  })
  
  # update the inputs
  observeEvent(preds_selected(), {
    lapply(seq_len(input$n_preds), function(i) {
      updateSelectInput(session,
                        inputId = paste0("Predictor_", i),
                        choices = c(input[[paste0("Predictor_", i)]],
                                    setdiff(var_names, preds_selected())))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Edit

Here a solution that lets you select for every input all the following choices:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

## store variable names
var_names <- mtcars %>% select(1:5) %>% colnames

ui <- fluidPage(
  ## select number of variables to use
  numericInput(inputId = "n_preds", 
               label = "Number Predictors", 
               value = 1, 
               min = 1,
               max = length(var_names)),
  # anchor where the inputs get added
  div(id = "add_vars")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  current_n_preds <- 0
  
  observeEvent(input$n_preds, {
    
    # add inputs
    if (input$n_preds > current_n_preds) {
      for (i in (current_n_preds + 1):input$n_preds) {
        if (i == 1) {
          possible_choices <- var_names
        } else {
          possible_choices <- setdiff(var_names, preds_selected()[1:(i - 1)])
        }
        insertUI(
          selector = "#add_vars",
          ui = div(
            id = paste0("Predictor_", i),
            selectInput(inputId = paste0("Predictor_", i),
                        label = paste0("Predictor ", i),
                        choices = possible_choices,
                        selected = possible_choices[1])
          )
        )
        
        current_n_preds <<- current_n_preds + 1
      }
    } else {
      # remove inputs
      for (i in current_n_preds:(input$n_preds + 1)) {
        removeUI(
          selector = paste0("#Predictor_", i)
        )
        current_n_preds <<- current_n_preds - 1
      }
    }
    
  })
  
  # vector of selected predictors
  preds_selected <- reactive({
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(input$n_preds), function(i) {
      input[[paste0("Predictor_", i)]]
    }))
  })
  
  # update the inputs
  observeEvent(preds_selected(), {
    lapply(seq_len(input$n_preds), function(i) {
      if (!is.null(input[[paste0("Predictor_", i)]])) {
        if (i == 1) {
          possible_choices <- var_names
        } else {
          possible_choices <- setdiff(var_names, preds_selected()[1:(i - 1)])
        }
        if (input[[paste0("Predictor_", i)]] %in% possible_choices) {
          new_value <- input[[paste0("Predictor_", i)]]
        } else {
          new_value <- possible_choices[1]
        }
        updateSelectInput(session,
                          inputId = paste0("Predictor_", i),
                          choices = possible_choices,
                          selected = new_value)
      }
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think this has a flaw in that as you increase `input$n_preds` you lose options in the predictors - if you set it to 5 then predictor 1 has to be `mpg`, predictor 2 has to be `cyl` and so on. It might be that depending on what calculations run after, the user needs to be able to set all 5 predictors but in a different ordering?
Edit - I say "flaw", that's too strong - I mean it gives a different user experience, and possibly not an intended one

Comment: Even with this different experience, I think this solutions best captures what I'm after. One benefit is that the previous selections are also retained even when predictors are added or remove. Thanks both for your responses. Is much appreciated!

Comment: @cwthom Thanks for your input! I've played a bit with it and I think now found a solution. DJC does my edit do what you want?

Comment: Yes indeed. Works great1

Comment: @starja just wanted to mention that i just asked another related question on here - it doesn't yet have your solution implemented but will soon :)

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more elegant ways of doing this than a loop, but you could use a combination of `insertUI` and `observeEvent` to create all the different observers you need dynamically. It helps to create a container in the UI into which to insert elements, and wrap each `selectInput` in a `div` so that you can remove them easily when the number of predictors changes:

```
# libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

# store variable names
var_names <- mtcars %>% select(1:5) %>% colnames

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # select number of variables to use
  numericInput(inputId = "n_preds", 
               label = "Number Predictors", 
               value = 1, 
               min = 1,
               max = length(var_names)),
  
  # create container for predictors to live in
  div(id = "preds-container")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$n_preds, {
    
    # clear out previous predictors
    removeUI(selector = ".pred", multiple = TRUE)
    
    # define function for updating select input
    updatePredictor <- function(session, input, i, var_names) {
      updateSelectInput(session, paste("predictor", i, sep = "_"),
                        
                        # get remaining possible options from previous inputs
                        choices = setdiff(
                          var_names, 
                          unlist(
                            reactiveValuesToList(input)[paste("predictor", 1:(i-1), sep = "_")]
                          ))
      )
    }
    
    # loop through each predictor
    for (i in seq_len(input$n_preds)) {
      
      # insert a new predictor
      insertUI(selector = "#preds-container",
               where = "beforeEnd",
               ui = div(class = "pred",
                        selectInput(inputId = paste("predictor", i, sep = "_"),
                                    label = paste("Predictor", i),
                                    choices = var_names)))
      
      # update to reflect previous choices
      updatePredictor(session, input, i, var_names)
      
      # create observers for each of the previous inputs to update the current one
      for (j in seq_len(i-1)) {
        observeEvent(
          
          # observe predictor j for j = 1, 2, ..., i-1
          eventExpr = input[[paste("predictor", j, sep = "_")]], 
          
          # update predictor i
          handlerExpr = updatePredictor(session, input, i, var_names),
          ignoreNULL = FALSE)
      }
    }
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you do this I'd probably recommend having a button to trigger any calculations/outputs which depend on the different predictors, otherwise you may get a lot of pointless re-rendering due to all the calls to `updateSelectInput`.

Comment: I think `insertUI`/`removeUI` is a good approach, however you first always remove every existing input, thereby the previously selected values are lost. I think your recommendation with the button for calculation is very good.

Comment: @starja that's true, and it would definitely be more efficient. I think the likely user behaviour would probably be to first fix a value for n though, so in practice I wonder whether it matters too much?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `conditionalPanel()` (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/conditionalPanel.html) to reactively display different UI inputs based on your input$inputID variable. This would need implementation on the UI function.

Alternatively, the `switch()` function also sounds like it might be able to get you where you need.