# Using UpdateTabsetPanel with Dynamic UI

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an app which allows the user to dynamically transform variables in a linear regression model to understand the impact that doing so has on regression diagnostics (residual plots etc.).

In the app below, you will see that the user has the option to log transform the target variable, and upon doing so, is presented with three types of log transformations to perform. This works fine with a single variable, but I'm trying to provide the ability to do so with the predictors as well. This gets particularly complicated because the number of predictors is not fixed and is based on a user's selection.

I recognize that one issue here is that I need to create a separate tabsetPanel for each predictor. For this reason, I created a function to create the tabsetPanel, which allows the user to specify the ID. This component of the app works fine, but when it comes time to try and render the dynamic parameter selections, to app doesn't function. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Apologies if the reproducible example below is a bit long - couldn't figure out a way to simplify without losing the scope of the general question.

```
## libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

## stored data objects, including variable and transformation names
dat <- mtcars
var_names <- dat %>% select(1:3) %>% colnames %>% sort
tran_names <- c("None", "Logarithmic")

## create conditional UI for transformation parameters
param_select <- function(object_name) {
  tabsetPanel(
    id = object_name,
    type = "hidden",
    tabPanel("None",
             fluidRow()),
    tabPanel("Logarithmic",
             fluidRow(column(width = 3, 
                             selectInput(inputId = "log_param",
                                         label = "Type:",
                                         choices = c("Natural", "Base 2", "Base 10"))))))
}

## create base UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(width = 2, 
                  ## input selector for target variable
                  selectInput(inputId = "target", 
                              label = "Target Variable", 
                              choices = var_names)),
           column(width = 2, 
                  ## input selector for target variable transformation, excluding polynomials
                  selectInput(inputId = "target_trans", 
                              label = "Select Transformation", 
                              choices = tran_names %>% .[.!="Polynomial"])),
           column(width = 8, param_select("params"))),
  ## input selector for number of predictors
  numericInput(inputId = "preds_n", 
               label = "Select Number of Predictors", 
               value = 1, 
               min = 1,
               max = length(var_names) - 1,
               width = "190px"),
  ## stored layout for dynamic UI
  fluidRow(column(width = 2, uiOutput("preds_ui")),
           column(width = 2, uiOutput("pred_trans_ui")),
           column(width = 8, uiOutput("pred_param_ui")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## parameter selections for target variable
  observeEvent(input$target_trans, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "params", selected = input$target_trans)
  }) 
  ## create objects to store individual predictors
  preds <- reactive(paste0("Predictor ", seq_len(input$preds_n)))
  output$preds_ui <- renderUI({
    preds() %>% map(~ selectInput(inputId = .x, 
                                  label = .x, 
                                  choices = var_names,
                                  selected = isolate(input[[.x]])) %||% "")
  })
  ## create objects to store individual predictors transformations
  pred_trans <- reactive(paste0("Transformation ", seq_len(input$preds_n)))
  output$pred_trans_ui <- renderUI({
    pred_trans() %>% map(~ selectInput(inputId = .x, 
                                       label = .x, 
                                       choices = tran_names,
                                       selected = isolate(input[[.x]])) %||% "")
  })
  ## create objects to store individual predictors transformations parameters
  ## this is where i'm stuck :(
  pred_params <- reactive(paste0("Parameter ", seq_len(input$preds_n)))
  pred_param_select <- reactive(pred_params() %>% 
                                  map(~param_select(object_name = .x) %>% 
                                        setNames(nm = .x)))
  output$pred_param_ui <- renderUI({
    pred_params() %>% 
      map(~observeEvent(input[[.x]], {
        updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "params", selected = input[[.x]])
      }))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that this question is an extension of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294921/dynamically-updating-choice-list-in-shiny-app/64295823#64295823).

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you want to do, especially with all the different `tabsetPanel`s. Some advice: 1. I wouldn't use any `Id`s that have whitespace, maybe this can lead to problems. 2. As you're building more complex UIs with associated functions, I would use modules. Then you can easily write the code for one variable, test that everything works and then tackle the problem how to apply this to a dynamic amount of variables. You can also use `insertUI` with modules, see some of my answers

Comment: Gotcha - I'll check those out. I was using tabsetPanel as that seemed to be the cleanest way to generator different parameter controls based on the transformation selected (i.e. if a logarithmic transformation was desired, can chose base 2, base 2, or natural log). In the actual use case, another transformation could be polynomial, in which case the parameter control would be a numericInput indicating the degrees